# Categories of definition for sites on spaces and sites on schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, definition, sheaf-theory, schemes

Starting with example 2.26 in [Vistoli's Notes](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf) he defines topological sites on $\mathsf{Top}$, while sites on schemes are always defined on a slice category $\mathsf{Sch}/X$. Why is this?

Comment: It's a cultural thing. In algebraic geometry one works over a base scheme, which may be something simple like a "point" ($\operatorname{Spec} k$ for some algebraically closed field $k$) or something more complicated like a space of parameters.

Comment: It's generally called relative point of view and attributed to Grothendieck. Take a look at the following pages: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck's_relative_point_of_view), [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relative+point+of+view), [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624553/grothendiecks-relative-point-of-view)